1 Corinthians 15:44 - why is there there is?
1 Corinthians 15:44b
Εἰ ἔστιν σῶμα ψυχικόν, ἔστιν καὶ [σῶμα] πνευματικόν.
If there is a natural-body there is a spirit-body (ESV)

Expositor's Greek Testament comments that "natural" is an inadequate gloss for ψυχικόν.
But does it also hide that the σῶμα πνευματικόν is logically implied by the σῶμα ψυχικόν? Because for a body to possess divinely-animating breath (a ψυχή), it must be a body that possesses breath. He's saying if a body is psychic it is also pneumatic. Or if a body is natural it is also spiritual. There is a somewhere where life comes from.
Why do the translations supply "there is" and read two distinct bodies?
σπείρεται σῶμα ψυχικόν, ἐγείρεται σῶμα πνευματικόν. Εἰ ἔστιν σῶμα ψυχικόν, ἔστιν καὶ πνευματικόν.
A body is sown natural; a body is raised spiritual. If a body is natural, it is also spiritual. [my translation]
I can't see as that does violence to the following line - if Christ's kenosis returns Adam's given spirit to God whence we may be remade

ChatGPT tells me this has been a point of difference between the Eastern Orthodox and some Contemporary Protestant views, versus some branches of Reformed theology and literalist interpretations.
But I couldn't find out much more than that. I think a good answer could shed light on the historic argument or tell me where to look it up.

I guess, grammatically it can be so, that is to say, the "if...then..." cause-effect correlation, like in a sentence: "If he is the only son of the king, then he is also the only legitimate candidate of the throne", that is to say, the second clause is a conclusion implied in the first clause. I do not think, though, that in your reading you imply that: "If there is (or: someone has) a physical body, then there is (i.e. this very someone has) also spiritual body", as if in physicality the spirituality is implied from the outset, like in the only sonship of a king a future kingship of this kid is implied. You rather think that without any cause-effect relation, Paul implies that natural body, qua natural body, is also a spiritual body, for it is impossible to be a natural body without being simultaneously also a spiritual body.
Even if grammatically possible, I do not think that it is contextually correct. First of all, it is the context where Paul makes clear differentiations of pairs of bodies: of men and of beast; of birds and of fishes; of heavenly and of earthly etc. In this context, when he mentions natural or soul-ly (ψυχικόν) body, he differentiates it from the spiritual body. And it is necessarily so! Why? Because "spiritual" means endowed by Holy Spirit, and Holy Spirit is not part of a creature qua creature, but is that in whom a creature should participate in order to become spiritual, that is to say, Spirit-endowed. No natural body qua natural can be also spiritual.
That is why Paul immediately brings examples of Adam and Christ: Adam is a creature, a created man, that's why, qua created man he is natural, psychic; but Christ is Father's co-eternal Logos who came into human flesh, and that's why Christ is called here "life-giving-Spirit" (please, do not accuse me in Sabelianism, I do not equate Hypostasis of the Son with that of the Holy Spirit, but in generic terms all three Hypostases, Father, Son and H. Ghost can be called "spirit", in the sense that there is nothing material in them).
In fact, a natural body cannot acquire spirituality and incorruptibility qua natural body, but for that it needs action of divine grace, which is not naturally present in humans, but is a gift from Above. Thus, in order to become imperishable, "the perishable should be clad in what is imperishable" (1 Cor 15:53), but what is imperishable into which the perishable body should be clothed? - of course God and His grace, for everything else, be it angel or archangel or whatsoever highest of creatures, are not per se imperishable, but perishable.
Therefore, correct is the translation: "If there is a soul-ly (natural) body, there is also a spiritual body" for "Εἰ ἔστιν σῶμα ψυχικόν, ἔστιν καὶ πνευματικόν".
